# problem running dbeaver, datagrip in version java archlinux

Tags: dbeaver, datagrip

When i run datagrip or dbeaver don't work, write this message   "version 1.8.0_351 of the jvm is not suitable"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv2OB.png)

I am install java other version but default verion java 8

Answer (score 0):

In archlinux have utils `archlinux-java` you can see install version java. Example
See you java version

```
java -version
```

`archlinux-java status` --- list you install version java

- java-11-openjdk
- java-17-openjdk
- java-19-openjdk
- java-8-openjdk/jre (default)

In this case java-8-openjdk/jre work in default.

You can set other version

```
archlinux-java set java-19-openjdk
```

After changing version you can try to run dbeaver or datagrip
datagrip 2022.3 needs a higher version than dbeaver